# cannot send Image to next View Controller - nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am downloading an image from my database and trying to send it to another viewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let dest = segue.destination as? ProfileTableViewController {
        print(self.logo)
        dest.LogoImageView.image = logo           //error shows up here 
        dest.Nametext.text = Name
        dest.Usernametext.text = Username
        dest.docID = docID
    }
```

My get Document function has this

```
imageID = document.data()["profilepic"] as! String
let StorageRef = self.store.reference(withPath: "proflepics/\(imageID).jpg")

StorageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
    if let error = error {
       print("error\(error)")
    } else {
       self.logo = UIImage(data: data!)
       print("downloading..")
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.reloadInputViews()
       }
                        
    }                  
}
```

Terminal shows:

```
downloading..

Optional(<UIImage:0x60000315fde0 anonymous {1125, 2436}>)

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/ikshitapuri//Me /TableViewController.swift, line 58
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set UIImageView of destination from your current ViewController because
you UIImageView is not loaded from NIB thats why it is nil. Send your image to destination ViewController by adding a parameter UIImage in your destination ViewController and then set UIImageView.
Following would be your destination ViewController:

import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet public weak var logoImageview: UIImageView!

public var logoImage: UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    logoImageview.image = logoImage
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

MY Bad i thought your image was encoded to string any ways

```
var newImage: UIImage! // ADD THIS

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let dest = segue.destination as? ProfileTableViewController {
    print(self.logo)
    newImage = self.logo // ADD THIS
    dest.LogoImageView.image = newImage.image      // ADD THIS      
    dest.Nametext.text = Name
    dest.Usernametext.text = Username
    dest.docID = docID
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the ImageView's image be an UIImage rather than a String?

Comment: I misunderstood your question let me know if this helps

Comment: Or you can simply add logo.image to line where error is showing